# Have site autocompletion for chat work with domain names as well as site titles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, chat, domain-names

The site-specific chat tab on https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site shows by default the chat rooms for one's own home site (crypto SE for me). There is a link "more sites", which allows selecting other sites. It has an auto-completion feature, which lets you input part of the site name, and shows all matching ones, so you can select the site you want.

[image]

If I input a domain name (like "diy" here) which does not directly relate to the site name ("home improvement"), I get no completion. **Could this be enabled, please?**

The similar completion for the moderators' close-as-off-topic text field understands the domain names (or has some other way of understanding acronyms not in the site name), so I suppose this should not too complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point, and indeed not too complicated – added to the next chat build.